# Can I recover my deleted world?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was playing terraria today, and my friend came and deleted the my world.

Is there a way for me to recover my world?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get back your deleted Terraria character?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194671/is-it-possible-to-get-back-your-deleted-terraria-character)

Comment: @RiotRuth I believe the dupe closure should be the other way around. This question's older and has more total upvotes on the question and answers. It also has significantly more views at 16k vs 4k.

Answer (score 3):

### Honestly, no.

This applies for all games on all iOS devices due to having no access to raw files and the way files are stored.

**So, why?**
iOS files are stored in a file architecture completely different to PC. The way files are stored is similar to how NBT tags work in Minecraft (yet are still completely different).
When data is changed, it does not leave an imprint behind, whereas Windows store files in a index format; ie. "Data Chunk 1, 2, 3 and 4 is file X", while iOS stores it in a compound or data structure.

Even if you could find a software to do this (there's quite a few out there), the data may be scrambled from the writing of other sectors in your phone's memory, making it unreadable.

*Side note: Pictures and music are stored in a different structure to apps.*

---

> "but i can still try my ipad isnt jailbreaked, can say please a few of the data retriver programs i still want to try"  – *Eric*
> [Can I recover my deleted world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189341/can-i-recover-my-deleted-world/189344?noredirect=1#comment256755_189344)

There are many software out there that do this. But sadly - None are free (that I could find).
All I can suggest is use the trials for them. They *should* have trial versions anyway, but watch out for the restrictions that the trials have (apart from the simple time limit).

Recovering is very simple.
Just plug in your device, let the program detect for "deleted files" and then choose what to recover.

#### Some programs you can use:

http://www.freeiphonedatarecovery.com (free version of FiPR)
http://www.aiseesoft.com/iphone-data-recovery/
http://www.leawo.org/ios-data-recovery/
http://www.datarecoveryforiphone.com/ios-data-recovery.html

Alternatively, restoring an earlier backup of your iOS device should also work as iTunes (on default) backs up your phone every time you upload new apps/songs/whatever to it... Unless you don't have a backup that was created close to (but still before) the world was deleted.

Comment: but i can still try my ipad isnt jailbreaked, can say please a few of the data retriver programs i still want to try

Comment: I didn't see him asking for more until you mentioned my name. (You see, the answer was BEFORE he asked for data retrieving programs.) - I'll go look for some.

Comment: @Unihedron - Noted, and done.

Comment: I know this is an iOS question, but it's worth noting that a deleted world on Windows IS gone forever.

Comment: (Unrelated to the Op's question, but related to your comment but..) @Kyle Actually. It depends. Programs like Recuva allows you to restore deleted files on the PC. That's if another file haven't already overwritten the memory chunk that was allocated to it.

Answer (score 0):

Restore your IOS device form an backup that has been created before the world deletion.

but be careful with that: because ALL data from ALL apps (contacts, calendar, other games, ...) will be restored.

there is no way to just restore your terraria world without a jailbreak.

Comment: I'm sure there are programs that let you choose what to restore. (And yes, restoring through iTunes replaces everything)

Comment: no. there are definitly no programms that let you chose what to restore. if there are some, show us.

Comment: iTools allows you to backup/view individual app's data (and the app itself). If you mean the backups that iTunes create - I'm not very sure if that's extractable. Just note that iTools does not allow you to recover deleted data. It's more of a data management app.

Comment: so this tools does not what OP wants...