# Is it possible to get back your deleted Terraria character?

Tags: ios, terraria-mobile

My brother accidentally deleted his character. Is he able to get back his stuff by backing up his whole iPod?

Comment: Do you mean, loading an existing backup? Creating a new backup will just take a copy of the devices current state (with the character deleted)

Answer (score 4):

No, he would not. Backing up only takes a copy of the devices current state. That character is gone forever **unless** you have an existing backup that was created recently. So, that character is probably gone for forever.